# How to determine when an API job is completed?

Tags: javascript, api, es6-promise, fetch-api, file-conversion

Please excuse any misconceptions I may have, I'm new to HTTP requests.

I am using a file conversion API (online-convert.com) to convert an uploaded MIDI file to MP3.
The conversion process involves 3 HTTP requests that must be completed serially, I'm using Fetch for this.

The 2nd HTTP request uploads the input file to the server, and the 3rd HTTP request gets the completed job details. The issue is, if I try to make the 3rd request as soon as the 2nd request is completed, then the response states that the conversion process is still underway and the output is not ready.

My naive solution was to set up an intervalic loop that continues to make this 3rd request every x milliseconds, until the response indicates that the job is complete. This feels like an unnatural solution, and I was wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Sorry if my question is specific to the API I'm using, but any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You can poll the api but their perferred way for users of the api is for you to send a callback url that they will do a request to once done (or at every status change) sending the completed details, https://apiv2.online-convert.com/docs/getting_started/job_callback.html

Comment: See some times files might be large or larger per say. Then you will have to wait for substantial amount of time and you cannot stop user from doing other things by just showing a loader, that's how API's are designed. The 3rd end point will always give you the status of convention if it's still happening. If it's done with or without errors it should ideally return you the results to show it to user.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you need a 3rd request if you can just delay your API from responding until after the conversion is complete with the converted file; it probably is an API specific issue rather than frontend.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks a lot, I'm not sure how I missed that webpage myself. In their example on that page, they use PHP to get the completed details by callback. Is it possible to do this with just javascript? Also, from my understanding, a callback is a function, so how would we provide a callback "url" for the API to call when it's done?

Comment: Callback can be a function that is called back to when something is done but can also be a url that the api "calls"(does their own http request to) back to send information to an api user. PHP is just a server side example, you can use whatever server side language you want, but the url will have to be to your server. They wouldn't be able to send a request to client side javascript.

Comment: Could you show some code? It might be that you did not code it right...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Patrick Evans' comments above.
I have decided to get the completed job's details by polling as opposed to by callback URL.

I was able to implement this easily using Fetch and async/await, and found this to be easier than setting up server side scripts for a simple web tool that probably did not require them.